# Доступ к тегу внутри неймспейса c помощью SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Как правильно получить данные из тега `NewDataSet`? Методы `children` и `registerxpathnamespace` возвращали пустые массивы.

```html
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
      <NewDataSet xmlns="">
        <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
          <CMan_Code>47156</CMan_Code>
      .............
```

Comment: Так выглядит решение в моем случае:

        `$manufacturesResponse = curl_exec($ch);
        $manufacturesXml = new SimpleXMLElement($manufacturesResponse);
        echo $manufacturesXml->Returned_DataSet->children('diffgr', true)->diffgram->children(null)->NewDataSet->asXML();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно с помощью метода [`children`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) (внимание на второй аргумент, навеорное из-за него у вас и не получилось самостоятельно) перейти в пространство имён, перейти на нужный элемент, а после этого этим же методом children вернуться в глобальное пространство, как-то вот так:

```
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
      <NewDataSet xmlns="">
        <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
          <CMan_Code>47156</CMan_Code>
        </Table>
      </NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</root>
XML;

var_dump(simplexml_load_string($xml)
    ->children('diffgr', true)
    ->diffgram
    ->children(null));
```